# What is the difference between these two network configuration files?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

The contents are similar, why the need for two files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `/etc/sysconfig/network` typically contains general information about networking on the system. Should interfaces even be activated? Which ones? What is the primary interface? What is this system's name and identity?

The other file you mention, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` is specific to the first ethernet interface, known in the linux world as eth0, and has details about whether to use DHCP or assign an IP address, whether THAT interface should be activated on boot, and so on. You will find one of these files for each interface on the system. Laptops for example often have `wlan0` as a wireless ethernet devices, and many systems with multiple network cards will keep going with `eth1`, `eth2` etc.

Comment: How does linux know which network device to use?

Comment: That's what routes are about. Routes define what interfaces to use to contact which addresses. You can see your route table by typing `ip route` on most unix systems. The interface that get's the default route is probably defined by your network config file mentioned above with an options such as `GATEWAYDEV`. Most other routes are built off of the ip and subnet data in the individual interface config files also mentioned above. Special routes can be added by hand or by other init files.

Comment: How to udnerstand the output of `ip route` above?

Comment: Your questions are wandering past the scope of a Question and Answer site for system and network administrators. If you have a specific questions, ask them as new questions. Otherwise I suggest you review some tutorials on linux networking such as http://tldp.org/LDP/nag2/index.html.